# Insert multiple copies of the same model file?

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Following the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/plugins/factory) I spawn a model using option 3.

Is there a way to spawn multiple models that use the same model file using this method?

using `GetModel->SetName` before spawning a new model doesn't seem to work... the names never update in the gazebo gui and the previous model just disappears.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/157/insert-multiple-copies-of-the-same-model-file?/) by [mcevoy.andy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/56/mcevoy.andy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This feature doesn't exist, but I've created a  [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/219/msgs-factory-doesnt-let-you-set-a-name-for) for it.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

```
     this code works for me

      for(int i=0;i<num_robots;i++)
      {
          sdf::SDFPtr modelSDF;
          modelSDF.reset(new sdf::SDF);  
          sdf::initFile("gazebo.sdf", modelSDF);
          sdf::readFile("models/wbr.model", modelSDF);
          sdf::ElementPtr modelElem = modelSDF->root->GetElement("model");
          std::string modelName = modelElem->GetValueString("name");
          modelName = modelElem->GetValueString("name") + "_" +
              boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i); ;
          modelElem->GetAttribute("name")->Set(modelName);
          modelElem->GetElement("pose")->Set(
                  math::Pose(math::Vector3(i, 0, 0), math::Quaternion(0, 0, 0)));

          //TODO: find sensors'name
          sdf::ElementPtr sensorElem = modelSDF->root->GetElement("model")->GetElement("link")->GetElement("sensor");
          if(sensorElem)
          {
              sensorElem->GetAttribute("name")->Set(modelElem->GetValueString("name") +"::"+ sensorElem->GetValueString("name")  );
          }
          _parent->InsertModelSDF(*modelSDF);
      }
```

---

Originally posted by [Wenguo Liu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/78/wenguo-liu/) with karma: 31 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1